# How to give background color for tabs in JSP

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, styles

I need to give Background color for Tabs in jsp.

```
<div id="tabs" style="width: 790px;">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1"><spring:message code="Tab1" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2"><spring:message code="Tab2" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3"><spring:message code="Tab3" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-4"><spring:message code="Tab4" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-5"><spring:message code="Tab5" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-6"><spring:message code="Tab6" /></a></li>
            </ul>
```

[image]

my tab background color should be orange color.

**Excepted result is**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attack UL tag:

```
#tabs ul { background-color: orange; }
```

Comment: Thanks.your answer give color for back of tab.But i need the Background color for tabs of tab heading alone.Please view my edited question.

Comment: #tabs ul li{ background-color: orange; }

Answer (score 2):

```
#tabs a { background-color: orange; }
```

Comment: Thanks.Please see my edited question and ur answer give color for my whole tab.sorry for not explaining fully

Comment: Please provide the CSS that you are using to display the tabs currently and we will be able to know what selector to use.

Answer (score 1):

after Attacking li tag, I got background color for tab alone.

```
 #tabs li { 
 display:inline; 
 background-color:orange;
 border-top: .1em solid #03c;
 border-left: .1em solid #03c;
 border-right: .1em solid #03c;
 }
```

Thanks for other friends help.